# Split 2D array to 3D array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some data and I want to split it twice. The data looks something like this:

```
var data = ['a1 b1 c1', 'a2 b2 c2Xa3 b3 c3Xa4 b4 c4', 'a5 b5 c5', 'a6 b6 c6Xa7 b7 c7', 'a8 b8 c8'];
```

As a first delimiter I use the 'X' character and this works fine:

```
var firstSplit = new Array(new Array());
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        firstSplit[i] = data[i].split('X');
```

But when I use the whitespace between the elements as a delimiter I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined", on the line of the second split.

```
var secondSplit = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
for(var i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < firstSplit[i].length; j++)
        secondSplit[i][j] = firstSplit[i][j].split(' ');
    }
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Every element should have been a separate one, but they already answered it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first split by `X` and map the result of the splitted values by space .

```js
var data = ['a1 b1 c1', 'a2 b2 c2Xa3 b3 c3Xa4 b4 c4', 'a5 b5 c5', 'a6 b6 c6Xa7 b7 c7', 'a8 b8 c8'],
    result = data.map(a => a.split('X').map(b => b.split(' ')));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.map would be a better way

```js
var data = ['a1 b1 c1', 'a2 b2 c2Xa3 b3 c3Xa4 b4 c4', 'a5 b5 c5', 'a6 b6 c6Xa7 b7 c7', 'a8 b8 c8'];

var result = data.map( (str) => {
   return str.split(' ');
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.push` to push each element to your result array.

```js
var data = ['a1 b1 c1', 'a2 b2 c2Xa3 b3 c3Xa4 b4 c4', 'a5 b5 c5', 'a6 b6 c6Xa7 b7 c7', 'a8 b8 c8'];

var firstSplit = new Array(new Array());
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  firstSplit[i] = data[i].split('X');
}

var secondSplit = [];
for (var i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < firstSplit[i].length; j++) {
    secondSplit.push(firstSplit[i][j].split(' '));
  }
}

console.log(secondSplit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert space to (-) then do you work

```
var str;
var firstSplit = new Array(new Array());
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
str = data[i].replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    firstSplit[i] = str.split('-');
}
```